# I'm trying add a javascript to java Mave project

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, maven

I'm trying to add Ajax request to my java Maven project which is MVC project and view done by HTML and model and controller are created by java.So I'm trying get data from more than 40k data-set to HTML side to using [DataTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) and Ajax request

I'm using WebServlet for create json object

```
@WebServlet("/PaginationServlet")
public class PaginationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public PaginationServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
     * HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");


        ChgResponse transactionsRes = LevelTwoDataLoader.loadAllTransactions();

        if (transactionsRes.isSuccess()) {

            List transactions = (List<ChgLevelTwoTransaction>) transactionsRes.getReturnData();
            //modelAndView.getModel().put("transactions", transactions);

            List allInactiveCustomersBeanList = AllTransactionsBean.getBeanList(transactions, DomainBeanImpl.TransactionID);
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            String json2 = gson.toJson(allInactiveCustomersBeanList);
            System.out.print(json2);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
     * HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```

I have added custom.js to load data to table using Ajax and DataTable

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#allAdminTransaction").DataTable( {
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once

        "ajax": {
            "url": "/PaginationServlet",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "trsID","name":"trsID","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "startTime","name":"startTime","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "endTime","name":"endTime","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "trsStatus","name":"trsStatus","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "rfID","name":"rfID","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "customerUserName","name":"customerUserName","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "amount","name":"amount","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "networkRef","name":"networkRef","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "networkOwner","name":"networkOwner","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "chgPointRef","name":"chgPointRef","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "chgPointOwner","name":"chgPointOwner","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "energyConsumption","name":"energyConsumption","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "sessionTime","name":"sessionTime","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "balance","name":"balance","autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "Options","name":"Options","autoWidth": true },
        ]
    });

});
```

and finally in HTML

```
    <section class="content-header">
    <h1 th:text="#{view.all.trs}">
        Widgets
    </h1>
</section>
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div id="totalOfColumn"></div>
                    <a target="new" th:href="@{/AllTransactionsByMonthPrint.html(selectDuration=${selectDuration})}"><h3 align="right" th:text="#{print.all.transactions}"></h3></a>
                    <table id="allAdminTransaction" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>StartTime</th>
                                <th>EndTime</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>NFCReference</th>
                                <th>CustomerName</th>
                                <th>ChargeAmount</th>
                                <th>NetworkName</th>
                                <th>NetworkOwner</th>
                                <th>ChargePointName</th>
                                <th>ChargePointOwner</th>
                                <th>EnergyConsumption</th>
                                <th>SessionTime</th>
                                <th>Balance</th>
                                <th>Options</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

but data not displaying HTML side

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: Good work so far! Maybe you should also ask a question :-)

Answer (score 0):

instead of System.out.print(json2) use:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(json2);
```